# How to use SQLAlchemy reflection with Sybase? [answer: turns out it's not supported!]

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, overriding, egg

I'm trying to learn more about the .egg concept and overriding methods in Python. Here's the error message I'm receiving:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/local/work/scripts/plmr/plmr_db.py", line 42, in <module>
    insp.reflecttable(reo_daily_table, column_list)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\engine\reflection.py", line 370, in reflecttable
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\engine\reflection.py", line 223, in get_columns
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 260, in get_columns
NotImplementedError
```

Here's the specific function from base.py:

```
def get_columns(self, connection, table_name, schema=None, **kw):
    """Return information about columns in `table_name`.

    Given a :class:`.Connection`, a string
    `table_name`, and an optional string `schema`, return column
    information as a list of dictionaries with these keys:

    name
      the column's name

    type
      [sqlalchemy.types#TypeEngine]

    nullable
      boolean

    default
      the column's default value

    autoincrement
      boolean

    sequence
      a dictionary of the form
          {'name' : str, 'start' :int, 'increment': int}

    Additional column attributes may be present.
    """

    raise NotImplementedError()
```

So my question is - do I override this function by writing a new method in my main module? Or am I missing a step somewhere along the way with my imports? Or am I just completely off track here?

Any and all help is appreciated :)

edit: adding my code

```
import sys
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select, Table, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.engine import reflection

dbPath = 'connection_string'
engine = create_engine(dbPath, echo=True)

connection = engine.connect()

#reflect tables into memory
meta = MetaData()
reo_daily_table = Table('reo_daily',meta)
insp = reflection.Inspector.from_engine(engine)
column_list=[...]
insp.reflecttable(reo_daily_table, column_list)

connection.close()
```

Comment: We don't really know anything about the code you've written, so we don't know where you went wrong.  We could speculate, but until we can actually see some of the code (preferrably a minimal example of just enough to recreate the error), all we can do is shoot in the dark.

Comment: The question is wrong altogether; you should not need to subclass or override anything there. You are just using SQLAlchemy incorrectly.

Comment: With table reflection, the actual database connection is very significant.  There's no way that `'connection_string'` can possibly be valid.  Also, `column_list=[...]` is not valid python.  You can replace the "username:password@host/db" portion of the connection url with dummies, but we really need your ***actual code***

Comment: @TokenMacGuy my dbPath is valid, I was able to connect to the db just fine - didn't want to publicly post the servername, username, password, etc. as for the columnlist, it is also populated with valid Python. e: here's the format of the connection string: 'sybase+pysybase://user:pass@server_dsn/tablename'

Comment: In any case, I'm able to follow your code, filling in what I beleive to be valid statements, but I do not encounter an error.  Please post enough detail for us to actually get the error you are having; I certainly haven't found a way.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy What other details can I provide to help clarify? Off the top of my head, I can enumerate that I'm connecting to a Sybase db using the python-sybase plugin, with the admin account/privileges. e: using version 0.7 of sqlalchemy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*EDIT*:

> [The Sybase dialect currently lacks the ability to reflect tables.](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#id1)

Comment: there it is, thanks a bunch man - saved me from wasting another 3 hours on this

Comment: And everything was easy to solve as soon as you provided enough information :D

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood completely. You do not need to subclass anything and this problem has nothing to do with eggs and .ini files at all.

You are not supposed to instantiate Inspector this way. If you read 
[SQLAlchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/schema.html#fine-grained-reflection-with-inspector) carefully, you will notice that you are not supposed to use Reflection constructor directly; instead you should write

```
insp = reflection.Inspector.from_engine(engine)
```

Comment: I updated the line per your suggestion; it's worth noting I followed the example listed [here (at the bottom of that section)](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/schema.html#fine-grained-reflection-with-inspector) when I originally wrote my code. Even with your suggested change, I'm still receiving the same error :(

Comment: However, no example on that page used Inspector(engine) but Inspector.from_engine(engine). By the way, I suggest you change the title of your question to "How to use SQLAlchemy reflection with Sybase" ;)